# How to make Toplevel() widget appear above main root window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have made a Toplevel widget but when it pops up it always appears below my root window. Is there an easy way I can make it come to the top most level when it pops up?

Comment: `Toplevel.lift` is probably what you want, just pass the root window as argument and the toplevel will be lifted above the root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `.lift()` method on a Toplevel widget:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("root")

top = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
top.title("top")
top.lift(root)
root.mainloop()
```

according to [this documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) you should be able to just use `top.lift()` to raise above all other windows but it didn't seem to work for me.

Edit: calling `top.lift()` without arguments does work when called during the mainloop, although since this question was specifically when starting the program that isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1):

try attributes

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("root")

top = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
top.attributes('-topmost', 'true')
top.title("top")

root.mainloop()
```